# {Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs} Not being identified by Scala

Tags: scala, emoji

I am trying to identify emojis within a sentence

```
def extractEmojiFromSentence (sentence: Any) : Seq[String] = {
    
    return raw"[\p{block=Emoticons}\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}]".r.findAllIn(sentence.toString).toSeq
   }
```

This gives the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
> Unknown character block name {Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}
> near index 112 [\p{block=Emoticons}\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and
> Pictographs}\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}]

Do I have to import some libraries into my build.sbt . Or which is the reason for the above error?

**UPDATE**

Im tyring the below code as suggested in the comment

```
val x = raw"\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}".r.findAllIn(mySentence.toString).toSeq
```

But im getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character block name {Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs} near index 45
\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}
                                             ^
```

Comment: val x = raw"\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}".r.findAllIn(sentence.toString).toSeq this code gives the error Unknown character block name {Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs} near index 45
\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}

Comment: If that is your reason how come val emojiValues =  raw"\p{block=Emoticons}".r.findAllIn(mySentence.toString).toSeq
         val   y =    raw"\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}".r.findAllIn(mySentence.toString).toSeq work successfully? Im asking y only previous regex mentioned is not working if you read it carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the regex engine in your JVM version does not recognize that block label. (Mine doesn't either.)

You can just supply the equivalent character range instead.

```
def extractEmojiFromSentence(sentence: String): Seq[String] =
  ("[\\p{block=Emoticons}" +
    "\\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}" +
    "\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]") //Supplemental Symbols & Pictographs
      .r.findAllIn(sentence).toSeq
```